# Probability of population $k$ at time $n$ in a Galton-Watson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

So we have a Galton-Watson process given by the random variable $X$ which has probabilities $\textbf{P}(X=k)=1/2^{k+1}$ for each $k$ a nonnegative integer, which has an associated generating function $G_X(s)=1/(2-s)$.

So, if we call the random variables which register the population in the n-th generation $Y_n$, these have associated generating functions $G_n(s)=\frac{n-(n-1)s}{n+1-ns}$. This can be easily proven by induction.

Now I'm asked to compute the probabilities $\textbf{P}(Y_n=k)$ for each $k$ and $n$. They also ask me to compute $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$, which are respectively $G_X'(1)=1$ and $G_X''(1)=2$. So we do know the probability of extinction is $1$ and, hence, $\textbf{P}(Y_n=k)$ must approach $0$ as $n$ grows for every positive $k$. How can we compute the explicit probabilities? And is this something that can normally be calculated for any Galton-Watson process or is it for a particularity of the distribution that we can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the probability-generating function for $Y_n$ we may readily compute the probabilities by differentiating:

$$
\mathbb P(Y_n=k) = \frac{G_n^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = \begin{cases}\frac n{1+n},& k=0\\ \frac{n^{k-1}}{(1+n)^{k+1}},& k>0. \end{cases}
$$
In general, finding a closed-form for the generating function of $Y_n$ given the distribution of $X$ may be more difficult.